# kaggle directly download input data from copied kernel

Tags: kaggle

How can I download all the input data from a kaggle kernel? For example this kernel: https://www.kaggle.com/davidmezzetti/cord-19-study-metadata-export.

Once you make a copy and have the option to edit, you have the ability to run the notebook and make changes.
One thing I have noticed is that anything that goes in the output directory is provided with an option of a download button next to the file icon. So I see that I can surely just read each and every file and write to the output but it seems like a waste.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebook you list contains two data sources;

- another notebook (https://www.kaggle.com/davidmezzetti/cord-19-analysis-with-sentence-embeddings)
- and a dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge)

You can use Kaggle's API to [retrieve a kernel's output](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#retrieve-a-kernels-output):

```py
kaggle kernels output davidmezzetti/cord-19-analysis-with-sentence-embeddings
```

And to [download dataset files](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#download-dataset-files):

```py
kaggle datasets download allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge
```